# Stop flash running from player ( outside browser) and accessing a web page

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-cirrus

Let's say i have a 2-player (multiplayer) game. 
What  if a user ( a hecker ) saves the swf, decompiles it, cheats into the code ( makes the game easy and winnable) , and runs the game from flash player ( As after decompiling and modifications, naturally it cannot be run from game-owner's server)

How can i restrict him playing the game via flash player (outside the browser) ?

What i think is, i must use PHP session on the page, where the flash game is being loaded. Can that do the trick ? Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't protect SWF files completely, but one thing you could do is check if url contains "localhost" or NOT the web url for the game. It is called site-locking.

Comment: I have no problem,even if it's decompiled. What i have problem is that, the swf doesnot connect, if modified. (Modification is only possible, if swf is extracted out of browser.)

Comment: Hmm, maybe now i don't fully understand the question. Can you phrase it in a different way?